Logo carousel resets abruptly and does not work like a smooth infinite loop
I'm attempting to create an endless loop of sliding logos, but on mobile and certain screen sizes (such as 13" Mac), it doesn't complete a full rotation. Instead, it resets just before the logo completes its swing.
I tried putting delays but I couldn't make it work.


@keyframes slide {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
}

.carousel-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 60px 0;
    background: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}

.carousel-container::before,
.carousel-container::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    content: "";
    z-index: 2;
}

.carousel-container::before {
    left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white);
}

.carousel-container::after {
    right: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white);
}

.carousel-container:hover .logos-slide {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.logo-sub-container {
    display: flex;
    gap: 2.5rem;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    animation: 35s slide infinite linear;
}

.trusted-logo-tag {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    line-height: 1.75rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.trusted-logo-image {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 40px;
    max-width: 300px;
}

/* Small */
@media (min-width: 640px) {
}

/* Medium */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .logo-sub-container {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
    }
}

/* Large */
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .trusted-logo-tag {
        margin-bottom: 2.25rem;
    }

    .trusted-logo-image {
        max-width: 290px;
    }
}
<section class="logo-container-section">
  <div class="all-logo-container">
      <span class="trusted-logo-tag"> logos </span>
      <div class="carousel-container">
          <div class="logo-sub-container logos-slide">
              <div>
                  <img
                      loading="lazy"
                      width="200"
                      height="50"
                      src="/static/images/logos/b.svg"
                      class="trusted-logo-image"
                      alt=""
                      decoding="async"
                  />
              </div>
              <div>
                  <img
                      loading="lazy"
                      width="200"
                      height="50"
                      src="/static/images/logos/a.svg"
                      class="trusted-logo-image"
                      alt=""
                      decoding="async"
                  />
              </div>
              <div>
                  <img
                      loading="lazy"
                      width="200"
                      height="50"
                      src="/static/images/logos/b.svg"
                      class="trusted-logo-image"
                      alt=""
                      decoding="async"
                  />
              </div>
              <div>
                  <img
                      loading="lazy"
                      width="200"
                      height="50"
                      src="/static/images/logos/a.svg"
                      class="trusted-logo-image"
                      alt=""
                      decoding="async"
                  />
              </div>
              <div>
                  <img
                      loading="lazy"
                      width="200"
                      height="50"
                      src="/static/images/logos/b.svg"
                      class="trusted-logo-image"
                      alt=""
                      decoding="async"
                  />
              </div>
              <div>
                  <img
                      loading="lazy"
                      width="200"
                      height="50"
                      src="/static/images/logos/a.svg"
                      class="trusted-logo-image"
                      alt=""
                      decoding="async"
                  />
              </div>
              <div>
                  <img
                      loading="lazy"
                      width="200"
                      height="50"
                      src="/static/images/logos/b.svg"
                      class="trusted-logo-image"
                      alt=""
                      decoding="async"
                  />
              </div>
              <div>
                  <img
                      loading="lazy"
                      width="200"
                      height="50"
                      src="/static/images/logos/a.svg"
                      class="trusted-logo-image"
                      alt=""
                      decoding="async"
                  />
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>



I tried changing the animation time and keyframes but couldn't make it work. I need something to make it work regardless of the screen size in an infinite smooth loop.

Could you edit the snippet so it shows the problem? eg put in some images we can see.
